# ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller Extension Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, extension-methods

I am new to mvc 3 and I'm using it with the asp.net membership provider....so I'd like to create an extension method to let me get the logged user GUID from any controller whitin my website

Something like that:

```
    public static Guid GetLoggedUser(this Controller controller)
    {
        return (Guid)Membership.GetUser(controller.User.Identity.Name).ProviderUserKey.ToString();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need the using Namespace on the top. Did you add that?

Comment: What exactly is the T used for in your code?  Your cast also won't work as you're casting a string to a Guid and returning it, even though the return type is a MembershipUser.  It's just all over the place wrong.

Comment: @MystereMan I've corrected my code....but look, I wrote it entirely because intellisense does not give me any help of what I have to do...

Comment: Still won't work, because you're casting a string to a Guid.  You need to just return the ProviderUserKey casted to the Guid, not the string result of it.

Comment: Ok @MystereMan, got it. But...I am not able to call this method from any controller in my project...I created a new namespace for this extension class, and imported it into the controller, but the extension method isnt loaded

Comment: @Andrey - did you make the extension class static as well?  `public static class Extension {}`

Comment: @MystereMan yes...and I put it under the App_Code or the Controllers folder and it didnt work....weird...but seems that the Namespace is not recognized (intellisense doesnt shows it)

Comment: @Andrey can you post your full extension source, and how you're trying to use it?  Try changing the namespace as well, sometimes namespace conflicts cause goofy errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use "User" property already on the ControllerBase class?

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetUser() 
    {
         var userName = User.Identity.Name;
    }
}
```

You can include additional information about your user by using a custom IPrincipal/IIdentity. [Here](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/02/effectiveformsauth.html)'s how it is done if using Forms Auth.

Comment: I am trying to adapt this webforms approach of how to store custom data about users, integrated with asp.net membership provider (part 18  of this article http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110310-1.aspx)...but I am using MVC and Entity framework to store the custom data in a custom table (related to the membership user table, by the user's Guid)